# Initializing a matrix (2D array) on condition or in switch case, in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, 2d

I want to send a matrix (3x3 array) to another function to multiply it by some stuff.
But I want the contents of this matrix to be conditional.

APPROCH #1:

```
 typedef float Mat3[3][3];

 void rotate(Point *p, float theta){

int choice = ((int)theta/90)%4;

switch(choice){
    case 0: matMult(p, {{1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}); break;
    case 1: matMult(p, {{0.0,-1.0,0.0}, {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}); break;
    case 2: matMult(p, {{-1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,-1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}); break;
    case 3: matMult(p, {{0.0,1.0,0.0}, {-1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}); break;
    default: matMult(p, {{1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}); break;
}
 }
```

APPROACH#2:

```
void rotate(Point *p, float theta){

int choice = ((int)theta/90)%4;
Mat3 matrix = NIL;
switch(choice){
    case 0: matrix = {{1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}; break;
    case 1: matrix = {{0.0,-1.0,0.0}, {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}; break;
    case 2: matrix = {{-1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,-1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}; break;
    case 3: matrix = {{0.0,1.0,0.0}, {-1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}; break;
    default: matrix = {{1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}; break;
}
  matMult(p, matrix);
  }
```

APPROACH#3

```
   void rotate(Point *p, float theta){

int choice = ((int)theta/90)%4;
switch(choice){
    case 0: Mat3 matrix = {{1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}; break;
    case 1: Mat3 matrix = {{0.0,-1.0,0.0}, {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}; break;
    case 2: Mat3 matrix = {{-1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,-1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}; break;
    case 3: Mat3 matrix = {{0.0,1.0,0.0}, {-1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}; break;
    default: Mat3 matrix = {{1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}; break;
}
  matMult(p, matrix);
  }
```

None of them, work and I get about 50 errors about } or ; being in the wrong place, which Im pretty sure is not the problem. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: please note that I have a this typredef for all 3 approaches:

typedef float Mat3[3][3];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices can't be assigned to in C, they can only be initialized or their individual components can be assigned.

There are several ways that you could proceed here, the simplest would
perhaps not be a `switch` but an array of `Mat3`

```
static Mat3 const matrix[] = {
 {{1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}},
 {{0.0,-1.0,0.0}, {1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}},
 {{-1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,-1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}},
 {{0.0,1.0,0.0}, {-1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}},
};

unsigned choice = ((unsigned)(theta/90))%4u;
matMult(p, matrix[choice]);
```

- I added `const` because it looks that this second parameter to your
  function is read-only.
- `static` has it allocated and initialized only once before real
  execution of the code.
- `unsigned` for the `choice` value guarantees the arithmetic with `%` really results in values from `0` to `3`, and not in something negative.

Comment: I gave it a +1 for the array assignment, but the "default" ([4]) is the same as the first element ([0]), I would remove the last one and call it matrices ... such that assignment is: `Mat3 matrix;  matrix=(value>=0 && value<4)?matrices[value]:matrices[0];`

Comment: @technosaurus, right there was one case too much. For the default case, as I have indicated it now with an `unsigned` you wouldn't have to worry. But still you can't do the assignment to a `matrix` as you are indicating. You would have to use a pointer to a `Mat3` or something like that.

Comment: Thats a good solution I didn't think of that. It is read only, so I will add the const as well. But why do you make it static? Any reason for using unsigned instead of int? is it just that the variable takes up half the memory? I agree, the default is pointless, I was putting it there for "safety" sort of, but I see that it would never default unless I modulo by something > 4 so its pointless.

Answer (score 0):

composite literal can use since C99.
you can write as follows: ,

```
void rotate(Point *p, float theta){
    int choice = ((int)theta/90)%4;

    switch(choice){
        case 0:  matMult(p, (Mat3){{1.0,0.0,0.0},  {0.0,1.0,0.0},  {0.0,0.0,1.0}}); break;
        case 1:  matMult(p, (Mat3){{0.0,-1.0,0.0}, {1.0,0.0,0.0},  {0.0,0.0,1.0}}); break;
        case 2:  matMult(p, (Mat3){{-1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,-1.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}); break;
        case 3:  matMult(p, (Mat3){{0.0,1.0,0.0},  {-1.0,0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0,1.0}}); break;
        default: matMult(p, (Mat3){{1.0,0.0,0.0},  {0.0,1.0,0.0},  {0.0,0.0,1.0}}); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what I was trying to do with the first approach, but I didn't add the cast. I added it but it didn't work, so I think I am working with an older version of C.

Comment: @user3064068 It is not possible to write a literal like this if you are using the old C.

Comment: How can u tell which C you are using? Does it just depend on the compiler? I was writing this on the 1st visual studio which came out around the millenium (yeah, really old...). I have the DevC++ but never got used to it

Comment: @user3064068 You can use clang, gcc that I know. You can not visual studio (MSVC) because MSVC is C89.